# MemoryMappedFile or serialization, speed on very large object

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping

I have a project that has a fairly complicated, nested (references calling the referenced objects up and down) object (class) stored in a dictionary like:

```
public static Dictionary<string, Object1> DObject { get; set; }
```

Object1 is a complicated class. It is not like a "address book" or "person info" class. The class itself has arrays, dictionaries of another object. Those object references class above it, etc.

Because the size of the DObject can be 1GB+ in memory, I'm going to serialize it to a file using BinaryFormatter. Because I need to load this object, I was thinking of using MemoryMappedFile. New keys and values might be added to the dictionary. Objects might have more data in them (added/updated), etc. Does the MMF change size? How do I access a certain key in the DObject in the memory mapped file? Is there a searching mechanism like a hashtable in memory so I can find a certain key like a dictionary and get its value? How is this MMF work anyway?

My ideal thought is. Have a large file on disk (2GB+). I update the object in the dictionary fast on the disk like having a memory saved on the disk. Everything is fast. Key-value look up all the way. I look up, edit the value, save, etc... I would have to have quick access to this 2GB+ object any time I want. If the WCF server restarts, I would need quick access to this 2GB+ size object. That's why I was thinking 1) serialization 2). load and read from/to MMF. My main concern is speed at this moment. I can't be reloading this 2GB data from scratch everytime I debug the project in other words (it takes long time).

Any suggestions, ideas and thoughts on how I should handle this situation.

Comment: for long term persistence, you might run into problem with binaryformatter (changing a namespace for example will quickly cause problems). For short term storage it might be ok, but be careful with memory use, I don't think you can serialize a 1Gb graph with binaryformatter in a 32bit process without problems. If you think mapping to tables gives you an impedance problem, perhaps you can consider a document database such as RavenDB which maps the entire document graph to JSON on disk and handles a lot of the perf issues for you?

Comment: Can any of these databases parse the object graph (20 interconnected classes) to a JSON/BSON and keeping all the references between them and then store? How does this work? My ideal thought is I feed DObject to RavenDB or MongoDB straight up and they serialize and store everything? What are the steps if I want to put DObject in RavenDB? I'm new to MongoDB, but heard a about it a lot.

Comment: Whether RavenDB will just swallow your object directly or not depends on how your object is structured. RavenDB uses JSon.NET so you can always start off by trying to dump the root object with Json.NET and see how far you get.

Comment: Ok. I'm going with MongoDB at this point. I will check out RavenDB later. MongoDB seems right. This data has to go to some kind of database I figure out now. I can't be serializing and saving data for long term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't keep `DObject` itself in a memory mapped file. .NET objects tend to move around all the time, and you can't force them to stay in one place in memory (you could pin them, but you really don't want to). You can serialize the object and write it to file, but that would mean writing more than 1GB of data each time.

Why not go the standard way, and 'serialize' your object to a set of database tables?

Comment: How would I do that? The object is not a simple "person info" or "contact information" list. The object itself has dictionary of key-value pairs. The value of the dictionary has "Lists" and those Lists probably has "Dictionary<string, object2>" in them. The object references the outer object, etc. If I had a simple string, int, fields in the class, I would save it to a database table. There are one-to-many connections happening in this value. In total there are about 20 classes contained in this value of this dictionary.

Comment: You can model everything you mentioned in database tables. You'll need about 20 tables if you have about 20 classes.

Comment: Ok. I think it is becoming a debate about serialization vs database store. I think it is a valid discussion.